# Auto Height Jetpack Compose Coil Image

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I am trying to show an image with fill width and auto height using Jetpack Compose Coil. I want the image to take the full width and auto height. But the image only showing when I specify a fixed height.

```kotlin
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        data = post.image
    ),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)
```

I tried with `.fillMaxHeight()` and `.fillMaxSize()` but it's not working. Is there any way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This happens when one of view `width`/`height` is calculated as zero, which means it shouldn't be displayed and no need to download it. Check out more about the reasons in [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186012457) on compose tracker.

You should make your size not being equal to zero. Depending you your layout it can be done with variations of width/height/aspect ratio modifiers.

If you'd like to get your image in original size, you can to add `size(OriginalSize)` to painter `builder`. This will force image to start loading. This parameter makes your view download and put into the memory full size of the image, without optimizing it for the current view. So use it carefully, only if you're sure the image won't be too big and you really can't add use size modifiers.

```
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        data = post.image,
        builder = {
            size(OriginalSize)
        },
    ),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one is the solution, finally.

Comment: Specifying min height/width for image also will force image loading. And seems like it doesn't impact image optimization. For example: Modifier.fillMaxWidth().defaultMinSize(minHeight = 1.dp)

Comment: Thanks, This was the issue. Update: rememberImagePainter is deprecated (LOL). the New painter code should look something like this 
```
 painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
                    ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current).data(data = imageData.imagePath)
                        .apply(block = fun ImageRequest.Builder.() {
                            size(Size.ORIGINAL)
                        }).build()
                ),
```
Even after 2+ years jepack compose is hell.

Answer (score 6):

With latest `Coil 2.1.0` you can do like this:

```
val model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(imageUrl)
            .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
            .crossfade(true)
            .build()
val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model)
Image(
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
     painter = painter,
     contentDescription = null,
     contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `size(OriginalSize)` that impacts image optimization, you can set min height/width for image (for example 1.dp). This will force image to start loading:

```
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(url),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 1.dp),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your image `OriginalSize` is to small for your composable you can also use `scale(Scale.FIT)` in your builder.

Your image will max fit your composable while keeping it's aspect ratio.

```
Image(
    rememberImagePainter(
        data = user?.photoUrl?:"",
        builder = {
            size(OriginalSize)
            scale(Scale.FIT)
            transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
        }
    ),
    contentDescription = "Picture",
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
)
```