# Update LazyColumn after API response in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, lazy-loading, android-jetpack-compose

I am completely new to Jetpack Compose AND Kotlin, but not to Android development in Java. Wanting to make first contact with both technologies, I wanted to make a really simple app which populates a LazyColumn with images from [Dog API](https://dog.ceo/dog-api/).

All the Retrofit connection part works OK, as I've managed to populate one card with a random puppy, but when the time comes to populate the list, it's just impossible. This is what happens:

1. The interface is created and a white screen is shown.
2. The API is called.
3. Wait about 20 seconds (there's about 400 images!).
4. `dogImages` gets updated automatically.
5. The LazyColumn never gets recomposed again so the white screen stays like that.

Do you have any ideas? I can't find any tutorial on this matter, just vague explanations about state for scroll listening.

Here's my code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val dogImages = mutableStateListOf<String>()

    @ExperimentalCoilApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            PuppyWallpapersTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    DogList(dogImages)
                    searchByName("poodle")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getRetrofit():Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://dog.ceo/api/breed/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    private fun searchByName(query: String) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val call = getRetrofit().create(APIService::class.java).getDogsByBreed("$query/images")
            val puppies = call.body()
            runOnUiThread {
                if (call.isSuccessful) {
                    val images = puppies?.images ?: emptyList()
                    dogImages.clear()
                    dogImages.addAll(images)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @ExperimentalCoilApi
    @Composable
    fun DogList(dogs: SnapshotStateList<String>) {
        LazyColumn() {
            items(dogs) { dog ->
                DogCard(dog)
            }
        }
    }

    @ExperimentalCoilApi
    @Composable
    fun DogCard(dog: String) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(15.dp),
            elevation = 10.dp
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = rememberImagePainter(dog),
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your view of the image cannot determine the aspect ratio before it loads, and it does not start loading because the calculated height is zero. See [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68908392/3585796) for more information.

Also a couple of tips about your code.

1. Storing state inside `MainActivity` is bad practice, you can use [view models](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state). Inside a view model you can use `viewModelScope`, which will be bound to your screen: all tasks will be cancelled, and the object will be destroyed when the screen is closed.
2. You should not make state-modifying calls directly from the view constructor, as you do with `searchByName`. This code can be called many times during recomposition, so your call will be repetitive. You should do this with [side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects). In this case you can use `LaunchedEffect`, but you can also do it in the `init` view model, because it will be created when your screen appears.
3. It's very convenient to pass Modifier as the last argument, in this case you don't need to add a comma at the end and you can easily add/remove modifiers.
4. You may have many composables, storing them all inside `MainActivity` is not very convenient. A good practice is to store them simply in a file, and separate them logically by files.

Your code can be updated to the following:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            PuppyWallpapersTheme {
                DogsListScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DogsListScreen(
    // pass the view model in this form for convenient testing
    viewModel: DogsModel = viewModel()
) {
    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
        DogList(viewModel.dogImages)
    }
}

@Composable
fun DogList(dogs: SnapshotStateList<String>) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(dogs) { dog ->
            DogCard(dog)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DogCard(dog: String) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(15.dp),
        elevation = 10.dp
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = rememberImagePainter(
                data = dog,
                builder = {
                    // don't use it blindly, it can be tricky.
                    // check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/68908392/3585796
                    size(OriginalSize)
                },
            ),
            contentDescription = null,
        )
    }
}

class DogsModel : ViewModel() {
    val dogImages = mutableStateListOf<String>()

    init {
        searchByName("poodle")
    }

    private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://dog.ceo/api/breed/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    private fun searchByName(query: String) {
        viewModelScope
            .launch {
                val call = getRetrofit()
                    .create(APIService::class.java)
                    .getDogsByBreed("$query/images")
                val puppies = call.body()
                if (call.isSuccessful) {
                    val images = puppies?.images ?: emptyList()
                    dogImages.clear()
                    dogImages.addAll(images)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Worked like a charm. I definitely have to read all the documentation you provided me because this topic's completely new for me. By the way, at ```fun DogsListScreen```, replace  ```viewModel: DogsModel = viewModel()``` with  ```viewModel: DogsModel =DogsModel()``` or an error will be thrown (function invoke is not found). Thanks again!

Comment: @xvlaze no, that's not a correct fix! `viewModel()` is not just creates a new object, it'll remember same object if function will be recalled(e.g. when you rotate device). Make sure you have correct import, and check out [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state)

Comment: @xvlaze also you can start from [tutorials](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial)

Comment: My error is ```Expression 'viewModel' of type 'DogsModel' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found".``` 

My imports are:

```import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel``` 
```import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope``` 

I couldn't find any wrong import at the documentation you provided me.

Comment: @xvlaze you need `import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel`

Comment: Life-saving! I was starting to mess with Gradle imports and was getting really confused. Thank you!